# Arduino NFC PN532 library error

Tags: arduino, nfc, spi

I am using this NFC Shield http://www.elecfreaks.com/wiki/index.php?title=RFID_/_NFC_Shield
and by using the provided library I am not able to run the examples.
This is the example code.

```
#include <PN532.h>

#define SCK 13
#define MOSI 11
#define SS 10
#define MISO 12

PN532 nfc(SCK, MISO, MOSI, SS);

void setup(void) {
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Hello!");

nfc.begin();

uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
}
// Got ok data, print it out!
Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX);
Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC);
Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);
Serial.print("Supports "); Serial.println(versiondata & 0xFF, HEX);

// configure board to read RFID tags and cards
nfc.SAMConfig();
}


void loop(void) {
uint32_t id;
// look for MiFare type cards
id = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A);

if (id != 0) {
    Serial.print("Read card #"); Serial.println(id);
}
}
```

and it gives this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNvl9.jpg

And these are the detailed errors

```
    In file included from readMifareTargetID.pde:1:
    C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:44: error: expected `)' before 'cs'
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:48: error: 'boolean' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:49: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:50: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:51: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:57: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:58: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:60: error: 'boolean' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:65: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:67: error: 'boolean' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:68: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:69: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:69: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:70: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:70: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:71: error: 'uint8_t' has not been declared
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:72: error: 'uint8_t' does not name a type
In file included from C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\cores\arduino/Arduino.h:213,
                 from readMifareTargetID.pde:8:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\mega/pins_arduino.h:35: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\mega/pins_arduino.h:36: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\mega/pins_arduino.h:37: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\arduino\variants\mega/pins_arduino.h:38: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
readMifareTargetID:8: error: no matching function for call to 'PN532::PN532(int, int, int, int)'
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:42: note: candidates are: PN532::PN532()
C:\Users\saqib\Documents\Arduino\libraries\PN532_SPI/PN532.h:42: note:                 PN532::PN532(const PN532&)
readMifareTargetID.pde: In function 'void setup()':
readMifareTargetID:16: error: 'class PN532' has no member named 'getFirmwareVersion'
readMifareTargetID:28: error: 'class PN532' has no member named 'SAMConfig'
readMifareTargetID.pde: In function 'void loop()':
readMifareTargetID:35: error: 'class PN532' has no member named 'readPassiveTargetID'
```

This is the .h file with the library

```
 // PN532 library by adafruit/ladyada
// MIT license

// authenticateBlock, readMemoryBlock, writeMemoryBlock contributed
// by Seeed Technology Inc (www.seeedstudio.com)


#include <Arduino.h>

#define PN532_PREAMBLE 0x00
#define PN532_STARTCODE1 0x00
#define PN532_STARTCODE2 0xFF
#define PN532_POSTAMBLE 0x00

#define PN532_HOSTTOPN532 0xD4

#define PN532_FIRMWAREVERSION 0x02
#define PN532_GETGENERALSTATUS 0x04
#define PN532_SAMCONFIGURATION  0x14
#define PN532_INLISTPASSIVETARGET 0x4A
#define PN532_INDATAEXCHANGE 0x40
#define PN532_MIFARE_READ 0x30
#define PN532_MIFARE_WRITE 0xA0

#define PN532_AUTH_WITH_KEYA 0x60
#define PN532_AUTH_WITH_KEYB 0x61


#define PN532_WAKEUP 0x55

#define  PN532_SPI_STATREAD 0x02
#define  PN532_SPI_DATAWRITE 0x01
#define  PN532_SPI_DATAREAD 0x03
#define  PN532_SPI_READY 0x01

#define PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A 0x0

#define KEY_A   1
#define KEY_B   2


class PN532{
public:
    PN532(uint8_t cs, uint8_t clk, uint8_t mosi, uint8_t miso);

    void begin(void);

    boolean SAMConfig(void);
    uint32_t getFirmwareVersion(void);
    uint32_t readPassiveTargetID(uint8_t cardbaudrate);
    uint32_t authenticateBlock( uint8_t cardnumber /*1 or 2*/,
                uint32_t cid /*Card NUID*/,
                uint8_t blockaddress /*0 to 63*/,
                uint8_t authtype /*Either KEY_A or KEY_B */,
                uint8_t * keys);

    uint32_t readMemoryBlock(uint8_t cardnumber /*1 or 2*/,uint8_t blockaddress /*0 to 63*/, uint8_t * block);
    uint32_t writeMemoryBlock(uint8_t cardnumber /*1 or 2*/,uint8_t blockaddress /*0 to 63*/, uint8_t * block);

    boolean sendCommandCheckAck(uint8_t *cmd, uint8_t cmdlen, uint16_t timeout = 1000);

    //

private:
    uint8_t _ss, _clk, _mosi, _miso;

    boolean spi_readack();
    uint8_t readspistatus(void);
    void readspidata(uint8_t* buff, uint8_t n);
    void spiwritecommand(uint8_t* cmd, uint8_t cmdlen);
    void spiwrite(uint8_t c);
    uint8_t spiread(void);
};
```

and this the .cpp file

```
// PN532 library by adafruit/ladyada
// MIT license

// authenticateBlock, readMemoryBlock, writeMemoryBlock contributed
// by Seeed Technology Inc (www.seeedstudio.com)

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "PN532.h"

//#define PN532DEBUG 1

byte pn532ack[] = {0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00};
byte pn532response_firmwarevers[] = {0x00, 0xFF, 0x06, 0xFA, 0xD5, 0x03};

#define PN532_PACKBUFFSIZ 64
byte pn532_packetbuffer[PN532_PACKBUFFSIZ];

PN532::PN532(uint8_t clk, uint8_t miso, uint8_t mosi, uint8_t ss) {
    _clk = clk;
    _miso = miso;
    _mosi = mosi;
    _ss = ss;

    pinMode(_ss, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(_clk, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(_mosi, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(_miso, INPUT);
}

void PN532::begin() {
    digitalWrite(_ss, LOW);

    delay(1000);

    // not exactly sure why but we have to send a dummy command to get synced up
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_FIRMWAREVERSION;
    sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 1);

    // ignore response!
}

uint32_t PN532::getFirmwareVersion(void) {
    uint32_t response;

    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_FIRMWAREVERSION;

    if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 1))
        return 0;

    // read data packet
    readspidata(pn532_packetbuffer, 12);
    // check some basic stuff
    if (0 != strncmp((char *)pn532_packetbuffer, (char *)pn532response_firmwarevers, 6)) {
        return 0;
    }

    response = pn532_packetbuffer[6];
    response <<= 8;
    response |= pn532_packetbuffer[7];
    response <<= 8;
    response |= pn532_packetbuffer[8];
    response <<= 8;
    response |= pn532_packetbuffer[9];

    return response;
}


// default timeout of one second
boolean PN532::sendCommandCheckAck(uint8_t *cmd, uint8_t cmdlen, uint16_t timeout) {
    uint16_t timer = 0;

    // write the command
    spiwritecommand(cmd, cmdlen);

    // Wait for chip to say its ready!
    while (readspistatus() != PN532_SPI_READY) {
        if (timeout != 0) {
            timer+=10;
            if (timer > timeout)
                return false;
        }
        delay(10);
    }

    // read acknowledgement
    if (!spi_readack()) {
        return false;
    }

    timer = 0;
    // Wait for chip to say its ready!
    while (readspistatus() != PN532_SPI_READY) {
        if (timeout != 0) {
            timer+=10;
            if (timer > timeout)
                return false;
        }
        delay(10);
    }

    return true; // ack'd command
}

boolean PN532::SAMConfig(void) {
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_SAMCONFIGURATION;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 0x01; // normal mode;
    pn532_packetbuffer[2] = 0x14; // timeout 50ms * 20 = 1 second
    pn532_packetbuffer[3] = 0x01; // use IRQ pin!

    if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 4))
        return false;

    // read data packet
    readspidata(pn532_packetbuffer, 8);

    return  (pn532_packetbuffer[5] == 0x15);
}

uint32_t PN532::authenticateBlock(uint8_t cardnumber /*1 or 2*/,uint32_t cid /*Card NUID*/, uint8_t blockaddress /*0 to 63*/,uint8_t authtype/*Either KEY_A or KEY_B */, uint8_t * keys) {
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_INDATAEXCHANGE;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = cardnumber;  // either card 1 or 2 (tested for card 1)
    if(authtype == KEY_A)
    {
        pn532_packetbuffer[2] = PN532_AUTH_WITH_KEYA;
    }
    else
    {
        pn532_packetbuffer[2] = PN532_AUTH_WITH_KEYB;
    }
    pn532_packetbuffer[3] = blockaddress; //This address can be 0-63 for MIFARE 1K card

    pn532_packetbuffer[4] = keys[0];
    pn532_packetbuffer[5] = keys[1];
    pn532_packetbuffer[6] = keys[2];
    pn532_packetbuffer[7] = keys[3];
    pn532_packetbuffer[8] = keys[4];
    pn532_packetbuffer[9] = keys[5];

    pn532_packetbuffer[10] = ((cid >> 24) & 0xFF);
    pn532_packetbuffer[11] = ((cid >> 16) & 0xFF);
    pn532_packetbuffer[12] = ((cid >> 8) & 0xFF);
    pn532_packetbuffer[13] = ((cid >> 0) & 0xFF);

    if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 14))
        return false;

    // read data packet
    readspidata(pn532_packetbuffer, 2+6);

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    for(int iter=0;iter<14;iter++)
    {
        Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[iter], HEX);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
    // check some basic stuff

    Serial.println("AUTH");
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<2+6;i++)
    {
        Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[i], HEX); Serial.println(" ");
    }
#endif

    if((pn532_packetbuffer[6] == 0x41) && (pn532_packetbuffer[7] == 0x00))
    {
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }

}

uint32_t PN532::readMemoryBlock(uint8_t cardnumber /*1 or 2*/,uint8_t blockaddress /*0 to 63*/, uint8_t * block) {
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_INDATAEXCHANGE;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = cardnumber;  // either card 1 or 2 (tested for card 1)
    pn532_packetbuffer[2] = PN532_MIFARE_READ;
    pn532_packetbuffer[3] = blockaddress; //This address can be 0-63 for MIFARE 1K card

    if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 4))
        return false;

    // read data packet
    readspidata(pn532_packetbuffer, 18+6);
    // check some basic stuff
#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.println("READ");
#endif
    for(uint8_t i=8;i<18+6;i++)
    {
        block[i-8] = pn532_packetbuffer[i];
#ifdef PN532DEBUG
        Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[i], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
#endif
    }
    if((pn532_packetbuffer[6] == 0x41) && (pn532_packetbuffer[7] == 0x00))
    {
    return true; //read successful
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }

}

//Do not write to Sector Trailer Block unless you know what you are doing.
uint32_t PN532::writeMemoryBlock(uint8_t cardnumber /*1 or 2*/,uint8_t blockaddress /*0 to 63*/, uint8_t * block) {
    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_INDATAEXCHANGE;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = cardnumber;  // either card 1 or 2 (tested for card 1)
    pn532_packetbuffer[2] = PN532_MIFARE_WRITE;
    pn532_packetbuffer[3] = blockaddress;

    for(uint8_t byte=0; byte <16; byte++)
    {
        pn532_packetbuffer[4+byte] = block[byte];
    }

    if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 20))
        return false;
    // read data packet
    readspidata(pn532_packetbuffer, 2+6);

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    // check some basic stuff
    Serial.println("WRITE");
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<2+6;i++)
    {
        Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[i], HEX); Serial.println(" ");
    }
#endif

    if((pn532_packetbuffer[6] == 0x41) && (pn532_packetbuffer[7] == 0x00))
    {
    return true; //write successful
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}

uint32_t PN532::readPassiveTargetID(uint8_t cardbaudrate) {
    uint32_t cid;

    pn532_packetbuffer[0] = PN532_INLISTPASSIVETARGET;
    pn532_packetbuffer[1] = 1;  // max 1 cards at once (we can set this to 2 later)
    pn532_packetbuffer[2] = cardbaudrate;

    if (! sendCommandCheckAck(pn532_packetbuffer, 3))
        return 0x0;  // no cards read

    // read data packet
    readspidata(pn532_packetbuffer, 20);
    // check some basic stuff

    Serial.print("Found "); Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[7], DEC); Serial.println(" tags");
    if (pn532_packetbuffer[7] != 1)
        return 0;

    uint16_t sens_res = pn532_packetbuffer[9];
    sens_res <<= 8;
    sens_res |= pn532_packetbuffer[10];
    Serial.print("Sens Response: 0x");  Serial.println(sens_res, HEX);
    Serial.print("Sel Response: 0x");  Serial.println(pn532_packetbuffer[11], HEX);
    cid = 0;
    for (uint8_t i=0; i< pn532_packetbuffer[12]; i++) {
        cid <<= 8;
        cid |= pn532_packetbuffer[13+i];
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[13+i], HEX);
    }

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.println("TargetID");
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        Serial.print(pn532_packetbuffer[i], HEX); Serial.println(" ");
    }
#endif  
    return cid;
}


/************** high level SPI */


boolean PN532::spi_readack() {
    uint8_t ackbuff[6];

    readspidata(ackbuff, 6);

    return (0 == strncmp((char *)ackbuff, (char *)pn532ack, 6));
}

/************** mid level SPI */

uint8_t PN532::readspistatus(void) {
    digitalWrite(_ss, LOW);
    delay(2);
    spiwrite(PN532_SPI_STATREAD);
    // read byte
    uint8_t x = spiread();



    digitalWrite(_ss, HIGH);
    return x;
}

void PN532::readspidata(uint8_t* buff, uint8_t n) {
    digitalWrite(_ss, LOW);
    delay(2);
    spiwrite(PN532_SPI_DATAREAD);

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.print("Reading: ");
#endif
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
        delay(1);
        buff[i] = spiread();
#ifdef PN532DEBUG
        Serial.print(" 0x");
        Serial.print(buff[i], HEX);
#endif
    }

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.println();
#endif

    digitalWrite(_ss, HIGH);
}

void PN532::spiwritecommand(uint8_t* cmd, uint8_t cmdlen) {
    uint8_t checksum;

    cmdlen++;

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.print("\nSending: ");
#endif

    digitalWrite(_ss, LOW);
    delay(2);     // or whatever the delay is for waking up the board
    spiwrite(PN532_SPI_DATAWRITE);

    checksum = PN532_PREAMBLE + PN532_PREAMBLE + PN532_STARTCODE2;
    spiwrite(PN532_PREAMBLE);
    spiwrite(PN532_PREAMBLE);
    spiwrite(PN532_STARTCODE2);

    spiwrite(cmdlen);
    uint8_t cmdlen_1=~cmdlen + 1;
    spiwrite(cmdlen_1);

    spiwrite(PN532_HOSTTOPN532);
    checksum += PN532_HOSTTOPN532;

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(PN532_PREAMBLE, HEX);
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(PN532_PREAMBLE, HEX);
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(PN532_STARTCODE2, HEX);
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(cmdlen, HEX);
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(cmdlen_1, HEX);
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(PN532_HOSTTOPN532, HEX);
#endif

    for (uint8_t i=0; i<cmdlen-1; i++) {
        spiwrite(cmd[i]);
        checksum += cmd[i];
#ifdef PN532DEBUG
        Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(cmd[i], HEX);
#endif
    }
    uint8_t checksum_1=~checksum;
    spiwrite(checksum_1);
    spiwrite(PN532_POSTAMBLE);
    digitalWrite(_ss, HIGH);

#ifdef PN532DEBUG
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(checksum_1, HEX);
    Serial.print(" 0x"); Serial.print(PN532_POSTAMBLE, HEX);
    Serial.println();
#endif
} 
/************** low level SPI */

void PN532::spiwrite(uint8_t c) {
    int8_t i;
    digitalWrite(_clk, HIGH);

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        digitalWrite(_clk, LOW);
        if (c & _BV(i)) {
            digitalWrite(_mosi, HIGH);
        } else {
            digitalWrite(_mosi, LOW);
        }
        digitalWrite(_clk, HIGH);
    }
}

uint8_t PN532::spiread(void) {
    int8_t i, x;
    x = 0;
    digitalWrite(_clk, HIGH);

    for (i=0; i<8; i++) {
        if (digitalRead(_miso)) {
            x |= _BV(i);
        }
        digitalWrite(_clk, LOW);
        digitalWrite(_clk, HIGH);
    }
    return x;
}
```

I am a beginner and any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont exactly know how it happened but I did try some things that I would like to mention which may help somebody else with this problem.
I deleted all my libraries of NFC(PN532) and added the original library using Arduino's own add library option.
Other than that I just changed my board to Uno and then changed it back to 2560 mega and compiled the sketch and it works now.

- Note:(FOR ANYBODY NEW WHO READS THIS) Anybody using Arduino 1.0 or greater for such libraries should edit the .h and .cpp files by removing WProgram.h with Arduino.h.

Answer (score 0):

you're not including the stdlib and stdbool headers that give you respectively the `uint8_t`/`uint32_t` type and `boolean` type, please consider adding this at the top of your files:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: Appreciate it but it gives the same error as the image in the link provided above even with these libs